# How to jUnit test the result of code in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have a process that runs in a thread (used as a realtime signal analysis process).  I want to feed that thread process a known input, and then test -- in jUnit -- that the output is correct.   I have a callback listener that can notify me when the thread finishes processing the data and I can run assertions on the result successfully by registering the test case itself as a listener.
   When those assertions fail, they do throw an exception.  But that exception is not registered as a failure by jUnit, presumably because they are happening outside of a test method.

How do I structure my jUnit test so that the test fails correctly after the listener returns?   Here's a simplified version of the code.

```
 public class PitchDetectionTest extends TestCase 
    implements EngineRunCompleteListener() {
  AudioData            fixtureData;
  PitchDetectionEngine pitchEngine;

  public void setUp() {
    fixtureData = <stuff to load audio data>;
  }

  public void testCorrectPitch() {
    pitchEngine = new PitchEngine(fixtureData);
    pitchEngine.setCompletionListener(this);
    pitchEngine.start();   
    // delay termination long enough for the engine to complete
    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  // gets called by the PitchEngine when it has finished processing all data in the
  // fixtureData.   This is the only method defined by interface    
  // EngineRunCompleteListener.
  public void notifyEngineRunComplete() {

    // The real code asserts things about the PitchEngine's results.   When they fail, 
    // an exception is thrown that I can see in the console, but this unit test still  
    // shows as 'success' in the jUnit interface.   What I want is to see 
    // testCorrectPitch() fail.
    assertTrue(false);  

  }

}

public class PitchEngine () {
  EngineRunCompleteListener completionListener();
  Thread myThread;

  public void start() {
    // other stuff
    myThread = new Thread(this);
    myThread.start();    
  }

  public void run() {
    while (some condition) {
      // do stuff with the data
    }
    if (engineRunCompleteListener != null) {
      engineRunCompleteListener.notifyEngineRunComplete();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: this may be useful - http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already have two threads running. Your junit thread, and the process thread (started by `myThread.start()`.
Off the top of my head, I can think of at least two options that you have, all of them involving moving the assertion away from `notifyEngineRunComplete`. For example:

- You can use `join` to wait for the process thread to finish, and then do your assertions (Javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)).
- You can put your junit thread to sleep by waiting on a monitor object, and then in your callback function notify this monitor. This way you'll know that the process has finished.
- You can use an `Executor` and a  `Future` object. I think this would be the coolest solution if it works with your classes (Javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)).

Comment: join() is the solution we ended up using.  I had to add a method to the engine class to return its thread, which feels slightly icky because it means adding methods to a class for the pure purpose of testing them, but it was otherwise very simple and it worked.   Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: you can add a method to the engine class called `joinMe()` or something like this, which performs the same functionality. This way the unit test thread can wait for the engine to finish without being aware of its internal thread

Comment: You should also consider using an atomicboolean to flag what happened in your other thread, and assert its value in the main thread after the join occured.

Comment: @yoni I went with the approach of the `ExecutorService` and `FutureTask`. I have to say this was the way to go, however this code has not been very readable. This is definitely the approach to take but the next question/investigation I will be doing is to figure out if we can/it is worth while to clean up this code.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to feed that thread process a known input, and then test -- in jUnit -- that the output is correct. I have a callback listener that can notify me when the thread finishes processing the data and I can run assertions on the result successfully by registering the test case itself as a listener.

Rather than starting a separate thread for `PitchEngine` inside your unit test, why not extract the `//do stuff with the data` logic in `PitchEngine` to another public method and simply invoke that in the unit test? I can't think of any reason to actually spawn the thread inside your unit test, since it sounds like all you really care about (in this unit test) is testing the processing logic.

Comment: This would be a great idea with the simplified version i've shown you here - sadly in this case running the "do stuff" in the engine involves hooking up a bunch of data processing objects and managing their interactions.  It depends on several methods in PitchEngine and several more in its superclass, and isn't easily extractable.   I can see some approaches to improving the modularization there, but they'd take more time than I have at the moment.

Comment: Have you looked into replacing those other objects with mocks in your `PitchEngineTest`?

Comment: Using mocks wouldn't help here; the test I'm trying to write is a full stack test of the pitch engine, confirming that it is detecting the correct pitch, given a sample audio waveform.   I need all the actual code running.

Answer (score 1):

if you must run the assertion code within the callback, wrap the callback method in a try catch.  catch any throwable and have a way of passing that exception back to the junit thread (some sort of shared thread state).  the junit thread then just re-throws any returned throwable.